# grep stringset matching after certain word

Tags: grep, xml

I have an xml file and I like to `grep` whatever is after the word "user=". Let say, contents of the xml file is something like,

```
id="2ZG66N" impl="BatchJob" type="BATCH" user="t2036sl"   
id="43EGTT" impl="BatchJob" type="BATCH" user="T8478AC"
```

The output I want:

```
t2036sl  
T8478AC
```

My code
`grep -Eo 'user="([^[:xdigit:]]+)' file.xml`

This gives wrong output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need PRCE to do that:

```
grep -oP 'user="\K[^"]*' inputfile
```

Comment: Yes, it gives answer what I am looking for. Can you explain `'user="\K[^"]*'`?

Comment: @Akand The `\K` means: "Match the part before but ignore it for the output."

Comment: Like all attempts to process XML using regular expressions, this is of course buggy, in the sense that it requires the XML to be written in a particular way. For example, it will fail if the XML has been serialized with whitespace around the "=" sign, or with single quotes rather than double quotes; it will also match an attribute called "non-user", or a "user" attribute that has been commented-out. It's much more robust to process XML using an XML parser and XPath.

Comment: @user32929 It seems a bit stupid to criticise me for providing a `grep` solution after the OP has asked for a `grep` solution. Instead of wasting my time with that explanation you could have written an answer yourself or at least made this a comment to the question.

Comment: I am not criticising you in the slightest; I am commenting that the answer, while accepted, has limitations that readers should be aware of.  People come to this site, they find a question with an accepted answer, and it is right that they should be warned that just because an answer is right for the OP, it might not be right for everyone.

Comment: Furthermore, I think it's important that when people ask "How do I use X to achieve Y", we make them aware that X might not be the best tool for the job. That could equally be done as a comment on the question or on the accepted answer; you shouldn't take it personally that I chose to put the comment on the answer.